# HTML mobile redirection - avoid opening in the app

Tags: html, redirect, mobile, http-redirect

I have a website redirecting traffic to Kayak.com, lately I noticed users that have the Kayak app installed (iOS / Android) on their device, are being redirected to the app, instead of remaining in the browser.

Sometimes the users would get a question "Open in the kayak app?", while for others it will immediately open the Kayak app.

I wanted to ask how to disable this behavior?
I want all users to remain within the browser, just open the URL in the browser without opening the app (similar behavior to Desktop).

The HTML redirection code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <h1> HTML redirection - how to avoid opening on the app / offering "open in the app?" </h1>
</head>

<body>
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="1;url=https://www.kayak.com" />
</body>
</html>
```

I don't have control of app installations or Kayak's website behavior.
I have tried replacing the HTML redirection with PHP redirection,
And tried JS redirection as well.
Both approaches result in the same outcome (opens in the app / offers to open the app).

For convenient testings I added this code to a web page :
http://www.hotels-bargains.com/htmlredirection.php

Any idea on how to keep the users inside the browser?